# Entity Framework model first error on mapping table

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I'm new to entity framework and when I'm creating some sample projects I got following error .

" Entity type 'StudentSubject' is not mapped."

Following is the table diagram.

[image]

The issue is it is not generating the mapping for StudentSubject which holds the records of many to many mapping of student and subject tables.

But if I introduce a new column as Id to table StudentSubject and make it the primary key and remove the composite primary key then it works. I want to know why is this happening and is the way I did is the rite way to do it in model first approach.

Comment: I've had similar problem before, but it was related to the nomenclature. The damn thing where the Framework mess up with singular/plural. Don't think it's the same issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your code but this is how I usually map it.  Note this requires no fluent api mapping

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName {get; set; }
    public string LastName {get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentSubject> StudentSubjects { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentSubject> StudentSubjects { get; set; }
}

public class StudentSubject
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int SubjectId{ get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the fluent api for mapping because of naming convention sometimes is not suit the requests.

Following code should be work as you desired;

```
protected override void OnModelCreating
   (DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasMany(t => t.Subject)
            .WithMany(t => t.Student)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("StudentSubjects");
                m.MapLeftKey("StudentId");
                m.MapRightKey("InstructorID");
            });
}
```